# If API id parameter doesn't exist check again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to return a random football player from an API. There is a 'player id' parameter you can pass to get a random player.

```
const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
const fetchApi = fetch(`https://soccer.someapi.com/api/v2.0/players/${id}?api_token=${API_KEY}`)
const response = await fetchApi;
const data = await response.json();
```

My problem is obviously I'm currently generating a random number between 1 and 1000 but an ID might not  exist on the API so the app will then throw a 403 error.

I'm ideally wanting to create a game which will always show a player. Is this possible? Can you check if there is an id and there isn't fetch again until there is one?

Can you do this or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing, you can do is create a while loop until it gives a valid player from the API.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to get a list of valid player numbers and select a random one of those. But if that's not possible, then a simple way is to use a do/while loop and keep fetching with a random number until one works. Something like this (not tested):

```
let playerInfo;

do {
    try {
        const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
        const fetchedPlayer = await fetch(`https://soccer.someapi.com/api/v2.0/players/${id}?api_token=${API_KEY}`)
        const playerInfo = await fetchedPlayer.json();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log('No player with that number', e);
    }
}
while (playerInfo === undefined)

// Carry on with playerInfo
```